# php array search key & value by value form other array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an reference array like this (the data amount is dynamic, about 3000 records)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DEPT] => FIN
            [KEYCODE] => AAAAA
            [TYPE] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DEPT] => SALE
            [KEYCODE] => BBBBB
            [TYPE] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DEPT] => SCM
            [KEYCODE] => CCCCC
            [TYPE] => 1
        )
)
```

and use the value of "TYPE" to search keys "[9][7][16][1]" and value of "KEYCODE" to search value of above keys in following array. (dynamic, about 5000 records)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Nick
            [9] => GGGGG
            [7] => AAAAA
            [16] => MMMMM
            [1] => KKKKK
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Chris
            [9] => PPPPP
            [7] => BBBBB
            [16] => ZZZZZ
            [1] => RRRRR
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Cathy
            [9] => SSSSS
            [7] => UUUUU
            [16] => JJJJJ
            [1] => AAAAA
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Allen
            [9] => FFFFF
            [7] => DDDDD
            [16] => WWWWW
            [1] => CCCCC
        )
)
```

the output array should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Chris
            [9] => PPPPP
            [7] => HHHHH
            [16] => ZZZZZ
            [1] => RRRRR
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Cathy
            [9] => SSSSS
            [7] => UUUUU
            [16] => JJJJJ
            [1] => XXXXX
        )
)
```

"Nick" have item [7]=> AAAAA and "Allen" have item [1]=> CCCCC, so delete from data array.
I know the way to delete array item, but no idea to implement compare and search by key/value pair from other array.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want to delete items from the second array if the search function matches the [KEYCODE] and [TYPE] ??

Comment: yes, delete [NAME] [9] [7] [16] [1] if finding total match item of [KEYCODE] and [TYPE]

Comment: You want to find the `KEYCODE` from the first array based on `TYPE` and then delete a whole record in the second one based on the found `KEYCODE`? Can there be multiple values of `KEYCODE` for the same `TYPE`?

Comment: [TYPE, KEYCODE] at first array is unique. But in second array may have same "TYPE" but different "KEYCODE", I edited the second array for more closer real data array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I understand from your question, here's a simple solution for your required task:

```
    $firstArr = array(
        0 => array(
            "DEPT" => 'FIN',
            'KEYCODE' => 'AAAAA',
            'TYPE' => 7
        ),
        1 => array(
            'DEPT' => 'SALE',
            'KEYCODE' => 'BBBBB',
            'TYPE' => 16
        ),
        2 => array(
            'DEPT' => 'SCM',
            'KEYCODE' => 'CCCCC',
            'TYPE' => 1
        )
    );

    $secondArr = array(
        0 => array(
            'NAME' => 'Nick',
            9 => 'GGGGG',
            7 => 'AAAAA',
            16 => 'MMMMM',
            1 => 'KKKKK',
        ),
        1 => array(
            'NAME' => 'Chris',
            9 => 'PPPPP',
            7 => 'HHHHH',
            16 => 'ZZZZZ',
            1 => 'RRRRR'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'NAME' => 'Cathy',
            9 => 'SSSSS',
            7 => 'UUUUU',
            16 => 'JJJJJ',
            1 => 'XXXXX'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'NAME' => 'Allen',
            9 => 'FFFFF',
            7 => 'DDDDD',
            16 => 'WWWWW',
            1 => 'CCCCC'
        )
    );

    foreach($firstArr as $row){
        foreach($secondArr as $i => $que){
            if(array_key_exists($row['TYPE'], $que) && $row['KEYCODE'] == $que[$row['TYPE']]){
                unset($secondArr[$i]); // deleting selected item from the array...
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($secondArr);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Output of the above code:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => Chris
        [9] => PPPPP
        [7] => HHHHH
        [16] => ZZZZZ
        [1] => RRRRR
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => Cathy
        [9] => SSSSS
        [7] => UUUUU
        [16] => JJJJJ
        [1] => XXXXX
    )

)
```